# How can i use AngularJs form validation with ng-model-options and ng-change together?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have two issues with `ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}"` and `ng-change`.

1. When user select a value from date picker and delete the value from
   the field required field message is showing that is correct. Now if
   user select value again required message is not going away until
   user make a off click.How to fix this issue ?
2. Somehow related to first issue once user select the value save button is not   enabled until user make a off click from the form.

How to display required message and enable the save button ? 
when user select the value it should trigger the validation event.
Just want to understand. Is it because i am using `ng-model-options` with `ng-change` ?

main.html

```
<form id="createRcsaFormName" name="createRcsaCycleForm" novalidate
            k-validate-on-blur="false">
    <div class="col-md-12>
        <input kendo-date-picker type="text" class="form-control"
            id="asessPrdStartDate" name="asessPrdStartDate"
                onkeydown="return false;"
                ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.asessPrdStartDate"
                ng-change="validateDate('asessPrdStartDate','asessPrdEndDate')"
                ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" required
                k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'">
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="createRcsaCycleForm.StartDate.$touched && createRcsaCycleForm.asessPrdStartDate.$error.required">Start Date is required</p>
    </div>
</form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
                ng-disabled="createRcsaCycleForm.$invalid"
                ng-click="submit()">Save
    </button>
```

Comment: You are explicitly telling it to wait with handling the value untill a blur event occurs. Do, if you want it directly, you have to remove that. As an alternative you can use ng-blur and ng-change side-by-side to get it working as desired.

Comment: So you are saying i need to remove ng-blur from the field to fix my both issues ?

Comment: Remove the updateOn: 'blur' and use ng-blur to handle stuff instead.

Comment: ok still little confuse i will remove ng-model-options and add ng-blur instead. what expressions i can use for ng-blur in above case ?

Comment: Well...the rest is up to you. Point is that you have to use those two separatly  since now ng-modal-options is blocking the call to validate and you want it to execute directly. You can use ng-blur side-by-side do do additional stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation let me try this approach and see how it works.